# What are the black dots that are at some windows edges?

Tags: window

I noticed that many windows have this kind of sun limiter at the edges and wondered what exactly they are.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> The black dots blend the border into the glass A: Windshield glass
>   contains a black enamel band (called the frit) around the periphery
>   that is baked into the glass. This black band includes a border of
>   dots. See figure. The band has an etched surface to enable adhesive to
>   bond to the glass, says a sales manager at Able Auto Glass. When car
>   manufacturers install the windshield, they bond the windshield to the
>   vehicle with adhesive placed on the etched part of the black enamel
>   glass area (inside surface). The outside of the enamel band shades the
>   adhesive from the Sun and protects it from ultraviolet radiation. The
>   band also serves a cosmetic purpose by covering up the adhesive and
>   gives the windshield edge "a more finished look."

http://www.reddit.com/r/whatisthisthing/comments/1xsoea/what_are_these_black_dots_on_the_edge_of_panes_of/

Answer (score 2):

it helps the adhesive bond to the glass, protects the glue from heat and sun exposure, and provides shade to passangers.